# Laravel strange behavior in 1 to Many relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, model

Very strange situation in Laravel 1 to Many relationships,
My User model

```
public function reminder(){

        return $this->hasMany(Reminder::class);
    }
```

Reminder Model

```
public function user(){

        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

When I try to get

```
dd(auth()->user()->reminder) -> null
$user_id = auth()->user()->id;
$user = User::findOrFail($user_id);
dd($user->reminder) -> success I got results.
```

Question is why I can't get relationship result using `auth()->user()->reminder`???

Comment: I think It's because of ```()``` , try ```auth()->user->reminder```, when you use ```auth()->user()```, it return collection not the model

Comment: @AmirJani I tried but it's giving this error Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::$user

Comment: @MuhammadTariq Try to remove parenthesis like this : auth()->user->reminder

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to import your model class into the respective model

User.php

```
use App\Reminder;

public function reminders()
{
    $this->hasMany(Reminder::class, 'user_id');
}
```

Comment: When we are using Reminder::class we don't need to use App\Reminder actully, and it didn't worked also!

Comment: Have you put 'auth' middleware to your route? Try to dd auth()->user(), is it returning null or the authenticated user object? auth()->user() will only return the the user object if you put auth middleware to your controller method

Comment: its returning object!

Comment: Are you sure the authenticated user has reminders in DB?

Comment: have you tried the above solution? `$request->user()->reminder;`

Answer (score 1):

Modify your public function reminder() to reminders(){.....}
and additionally you can try also

```
public function reminders(){
    return $this->hasMany(Reminder::class, 'user_id', 'id'); 
}
```

Comment: $user = User::findOrFail($user_id);
dd($user->reminder) 
if you get the collection by it, there is a problem with auth()
use Auth; 
and try Auth::user()->reminder;

Comment: there something else wrong! I tried all these possible solutions already!

Answer (score 1):

I've run not so fresh laravel 5.8 install with empty laravel. Both methods worked for me. I only had to be sure, that my user is logged in and the namespace is absolute. I've just put your code into routes/web. Here's my code:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    \Auth::loginUsingId(1);
    dd(auth()->user()->reminder);
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $user = \App\User::findOrFail($user_id);
    dd($user->reminder); 
 });
```

Please check if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Auth logged in user was actually given id from another table i.e Admin

Moving relationship to Admin Call did worked.